# Can't read params from navigation.navigate

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm building an app that detects sensors and shows the user information about the sensors automatically.

So I created a main page with a single tab to show a label saying "detecting", and when the system detects a sensor, a new page is opened with three tabs containing information about the sensor.

But I'm having some difficulties because I can't pass the sensor ID to the second page. I would like to know what am I doing wrong, and why the Props.params is undefined.

I'm trying to do something like that:

[image]

Main page tab navigator:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer independent={true} >
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Detection"
            component={DetectScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: 'Detect',
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="motion-sensor" color={color} size={size} />
              ),
            }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }

function DetectScreen() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Detect' screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name='Detect' component={DetectionScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Sensor' component={SensorScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function DetectionScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['#000000', '#FFFFFF']}
        style={styles.main_container}>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <Detect navigation={navigation} />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </LinearGradient>
    </SafeAreaView>)
}

function SensorScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['#000000', '#FFFFFF']}
        style={styles.main_container}>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.main_subcontainer}>
          <Sensor navigation={navigation}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </LinearGradient>
    </SafeAreaView>)
}
```

Detect class

```
export class Detect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        startDetecting()
    }
    
    startDetecting(){
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Sensor", {
            params:{
              sensorId: 123
           }
        })
    }
}
```

Opening screen when the sensor is detected

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function TabStack() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Configurations"
      >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="FirstScreen"
        component={FirstScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'First'
        }} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="SecondScreen"
        component={SecondScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Second'
        }} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="ThirdScreen"
        component={ThirdScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Third'
        }} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export class Sensor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props.params) //props.params is Undefined
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer
        independent={true}
      >
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Sensor"
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false
          }}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="TabStack"
            component={TabStack}
            options={{ title: 'Tab Stack' }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `this.props.navigation.getParam('sensorId', 'Default value')` is react navigation v4. or in v5 you can do `const {navigation, route } = this.props` and then get the value like `const { sensorId } = route.params`

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't work. I think that the problem is with the navigation structure. The route is undefined too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add route parameter to DetectionScreen function
2. Access sensorId in DetectionScreen by `route.params.sensorId`
3. You can then pass this value to the Detect component
4. Access this value in Detect component using `this.props.sensordId`

code below

```
function DetectionScreen({ navigation,route }) {
return (
<SafeAreaView>
  <LinearGradient
    colors={['#000000', '#FFFFFF']}
    style={styles.main_container}>
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Detect sensorId={route.params.sensorId} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </LinearGradient>
</SafeAreaView>)
}
```

as explained here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me, the problem was that I was using one route name in my App Navigator, and another when I was navigating (and passing the params) to the page from another page. Changing them to be the same route name fixed the issue for me.